# Separation of variables differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve this equation by separation of variables: xu'=3u.

I see that the answer should be u(x)=$cx^3$, but since I have no knowledge of differential equations, can someone provide the steps?

Comment: Do you know to solve any differential equation by separation of variables?

Comment: No, I don't know this at all

Comment: See [wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Example_.28I.29).

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint: }$ Assuming $u$ is a function of $x$, $u' = \frac{du}{dx}$. The trick with separable differential equations is separating the differentials and their respective variables. In this example: $$x\frac{du}{dx} = 3u \longrightarrow \frac{du}{u} = 3\frac{dx}{x}$$ Integrate on both sides and find $u$.

Comment: I got $u=x^3$, but where does the C come from? It seems to me that it would change the differential equation.

Comment: @user146166 Add your work to the question so people can pinpoint your mistakes.

Comment: @user146166 Once you integrate, you'll get a constant $C_1$, let $C_1 = \log{C}$ and use properties of logarithms. (Being $\log$ the natural logarithm).